# How to create Nested Loops in TreeNode C#

Tags: c#

I have written a nested-loop for adding Tree-Nodes, problem is that **index i** never increments to **1**.

In For Each Loop: where there are no more child nodes in first Parent Node, the loop stops in **index j** and does not go back to **index i** to increment to **1**.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 23; j++)
    {
        foreach (var item in myDictionaryReconstructed)
        {
            if ("TreeNode: " + item.Key == treeView1.Nodes[i].Nodes[j].ToString())
            {
                treeView1.Nodes[i].Nodes[j].Nodes.Add(item.Value);
                treeView1.ExpandAll();
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```

***For Example:***

**Parent Node 1**
 - Sub-Node 1
 - Sub-Node 2
 - Sub-Node 3

**Parent Node 2**
 - Sub-Node 1
 -

**Parent Node 3**
 - Sub-Node 1

The Program executes upto Parent Node - 1 and Sub-Node 3. 
When the sub-node is 4 being checked and it's not found, the program just stops there, instead of moving to next parent node.

**Exception:**
Specified Argument was out of range of valid values Parameter name index.

Answer to duplicate: after discussing later I found the exception above, my question was posted earlier before I didn't know that it's an index exception.

Comment: can you provide some output or something else that can help ?

Comment: Something doesn't seem right about this. Are you sure that the inner loops actually complete?

Comment: How did you come to that conclusion? During Debug? It would be helpful if you provide a sample structure of the `Tree`, and the items inside `myDictionaryReconstructed`. Also, you sure you don't have an exception of some sort?

Comment: Do you *really* have 22 nodes and each have 22 sub-nodes? If not, you will get an exception

Comment: @OfirWinegarten I have 22 nodes and each node have 2-3 sub nodes.

Comment: @OfirWinegarten I just put the foreach loop of dictionary in try catch block, it freezes  interface for 2-3 seconds and completes the loop with correct result now.

Comment: @OfirWinegarten Exception Received: Specified Arguement was out of range of valid values Parameter name index. 
I don't know how to count the nodes length, should I be counting, parent node length or the sub-node length.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f)

Comment: @OfirWinegarten Exception is Thrown after Sub-Node - 3

Comment: Makes sense, since there's no sub-node 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to our discussion in the comments above,

The following code throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

```
treeView1.Nodes[i].Nodes[j]
```

When `i` or `j` are greater than the number of Nodes that you actually have the exception is raised, as it would be with any other array.

You could do this with `foreach` or instead of using the magic number (23) use `Nodes.Count`.

So your code could look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < treeView1.Nodes.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < treeView1.Nodes[i].Nodes.Count; j++)
    {
        foreach (var item in myDictionaryReconstructed)
        {
            if ("TreeNode: " + item.Key == treeView1.Nodes[i].Nodes[j].ToString())
            {
                treeView1.Nodes[i].Nodes[j].Nodes.Add(item.Value);
                treeView1.ExpandAll();
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```